# Can we export a function made available through a static library

Tags: dynamic, dll, static, import, export

I have a static library say "*A.lib*" which contains a function `int foo()`. I have another dll say "*B.dll*" which consumes *A.lib* and uses the function `foo()` and also exports some other functions. Is it possible to export the function `int foo()` (imported from A.lib) from B.dll so that it can be consumed in a third dll say "*C.dll*".

I want to know whether it is possible or not, I dont want workarounds like making *A.lib* available to the *C.dll*. Also, I am not concerned if this is a bad design or not.

Thanks very much for your patience to read this through.

Comment: Using a .def file to explicitly declare your exports produces the least amount of mess.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement - just found a different solution:

Assuming that A.lib has an A.h (that is consumed by source files used to build B.dll e.g. assuming that A.h contains prototypes for functions contained in A.lib), just add the following in A.h:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:_foo")
```

This will instruct the linker to export `foo()` when building B.dll.  Note the leading underscore - it is there because that's the true name of the symbol for `foo()` contained in A.lib (use `dumpbin /symbols A.lib | findstr foo` to see it).  In my example `foo()` was using the `__cdecl` calling convention, but if you use `__stdcall()` or compile as C++, you'll get different name decoration, so you'll have to adjust the `#pragma` statement above as a result.

It doesn't matter if A.h gets included by many source files in B.dll - the linker doesn't complain if the exact same definition is made multiple times.

One "advantage" to this approach is that you don't even have to use the `__declspec(dllexport)` specifier on `foo()` in A.lib ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible but any code example is language dependent.
(for example in C you may simply export a function with the same name and C.dll will see it)

Comment: I guess I had been a bit vague about my problem. More specifically is this possible on windows using visual studio C++? Because as I see I am not able to do so - In C.dll I can see use the symbols that B.dll itself exports but I am not able to access foo, though I have declared it as an export symbol in B.dll.<BR> Suprisingly enough, I can even see the symbol foo when I do a dumpbin on B.dll. <BR> Thanks for your prompt reply. <BR> Update: If I make A.lib dynamic i.e. create A.dll instead of A.lib then dumpbin of B.dll does conatin a reference to foo().

Comment: I **guess** name collision may confuse a little bit the compiler, you have __declspec(export) and __declspec(import) for a function with the same prototype. I think, if you can't add a dependency from C to A, then you have to change the function name.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow that - change the function name in *A.lib*?? Also, I would again reemphasize that the function foo is not visible in dumpbin of *B.dll*.

Comment: I understand but in B.dll you have somehting like: void __declspec(export) foo(); AND void __declspec(import) foo(); so what's the right one?

Comment: Technically, I would not need a *dllimport* in this case because I am linking to a static library. All I need is a *dllexport* of *foo* from *B.dll*. Btw, I could succeed making foo appear in the dumpbin of *B.dll* by taking its address in the code (in *B.dll*) - I think the compiler was inlining *foo* in *B.dll*.

Comment: Sorry I started to be confused! If _A_ is dynamic linked you need a _dllimport_. Anyway, even if it's inlining the call to _foo_ it'll inline the call from the exported function...
I mean: you have a function declared in A.dll and you have **another** function declared in B.dll so even if it inlines the first one the second one is still exported!